# Need help deciphering PHP error message

Tags: php

How to overcome from below error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant temp_members_db - assumed 'temp_members_db' 
in /var/www/signup_ac.php on line 10 Cannot send Confirmation link to 
your e-mail address
```

Below is the Code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

include('config.php');

// table name
$tbl_name=temp_members_db;

// Random confirmation code
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

// Insert data into database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, name, email, password, country)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email
if($result){

// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;

// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";

// From
$header="from: your name <your email>";

// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
//$message.="http://www.yourweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
$message.="http://localhost/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";

// send email   
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

}

// if not found
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}

?>
```

Comment: If you show us what is on line 10 of signup_ac.php we can probably give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: As stated by @user below, you have [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks) problems

Answer (score 9):

Either you forgot a `$` or you forgot some quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using `temp_members_db` as an array key but didn’t quote the string properly:

```
$arr[temp_members_db] ⟶ $arr['temp_members_db']
```

See also [*Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar):

> This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an undefined constant (`bar`) rather than a string (`'bar'` - notice the quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named `bar`, then PHP will substitute in the string `'bar'` and use that.

Comment: I ****ing hate this behaviour. Addressing a non-existant constant should result in an error, not a ***ing notice.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, though it's not actually related to arrays.

Comment: @Pekka: My sentiments exactly. In some aspects PHP is simply too tolerant.

Comment: @Gumbo yeah. And it will never change, because that would break too many existing applications. Maybe it's time to fork PHP :)

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Now after Aos posted some code, we see that this error is caused by an unquoted “string” that is not used as an array key. To be honest, I’ve never thought that PHP does even allow unquoted “strings” that are not used as an array key.

Comment: @Pekka: I would be glad to see a stricter variant of PHP too.

Comment: You can build your own version of Even Stricter PHP is you please. Just set a custom error handler that aborts execution on the first *notice*.

Answer (score 1):

Is it me, or there is a huge SQL-injection and Mail-injection in this code ?

(And it is not just some fancy words, it means you not fully understand what you are doing...)

And by the way PHP6 is not arrived yet, so function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is still exists, and it is still necessary ...

Comment: No reason for a downvote - there *are* huge vulnerabilities here, and new users can't comment. +1 to even out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

include('config.php');

// table name
$tbl_name=temp_members_db;
```

You're either missing quotes:

```
$tbl_name='temp_members_db';
```

or the constant definition:

```
define('temp_members_d', 'whatever');
```

Comment: Or `config.php` defines `$temp_members_db`.